# my facebook app not appear in facebook search result

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Hi i have create a facebook app and a page named ["Event Finder - Upcoming Events, Find Local Events"](http://app.eventfinder.info). when i write on facebook search bar, Event Finder and go on "see more results" i not see my app.
With another my app ["My links, find my posted links, history timeline"](http://app.linkfinder.me), when i write posted links, on the serach bar, i see the results.Why?
When i have created "Event Finder - Upcoming Events, Find Local Events" i see this app on the results, after some days is disappeared.
A ban from search results is possible? if the response is yes, when Facebook ban from the search results?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  I've read that FB has to rebuild their search index, which they do every 2-4 weeks, so it can take awhile for your app to be added.  Your app also has to have 10 monthly users.  However, there could be another reason, because my app has been out for 6 weeks and has way over 10 monthly users, but it still isn't showing up in the search.  Please reply if/when you find out what your problem was.